# jQuery ajax not sending anything

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have a site built with CakePHP. I would like to send an HTTP post with jquery ajax (I know that cakePHP has a helper for this but I would like to do it with jQuery because it's more flexible).

My jquery function:

```
function warrantyqueryPost(ServiceorderSerial, ServiceorderUserId){

    var data = { 'data[Warrantyqueries][serial]' : 123, 'data[Warrantyqueries][user_id]' : 4  }

    var url = '/warrantyqueries/add';

    alert(url);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function (){
            alert('hat geklappt');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('nein');
        }
    });

    alert('test');
}
```

For test purposes key-value pairs are hardcoded (to avoid any mistake). The function is called but the ajax call is not executed. Nothing happens.

The absolute url of the post method is

```
http://localhost:8080/serviceordersystem/index.php/warrantyqueries/add
```

I even tried that, no success.

For test reasons I tried a very simple ajax get:

```
function warrantyquery(ServiceorderSerial, ServiceorderUserId){
    alert('test');
    var url = '/serviceordersystem/index.php';

    var jqxhr = $.get(url, function() {
        alert( "success" );
    })
        .done(function() {
            alert( "second success" );
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
        })
        .always(function() {
            alert( "finished" );
        });
}
```

Nothing happens. If I call the address with my browser I get the correct string returned.

**Update**
For me it really looks like jquery is not working! Stand by, I will check ...

Comment: See whats ur browser's console saying..

Comment: Please don't use alerts() to troubleshoot with. Use console.log() instead. Open your browser's developer tools and watch the request / response cycle. You'll also see any JavaScript / jQuery errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the linked jquery library was corrupted. Downloaded the library again and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Is the url right with this 'index.php' ?

```
http://localhost:8080/serviceordersystem/index.php/warrantyqueries/add
```

shouldn't be:

```
http://localhost:8080/serviceordersystem/warrantyqueries/add
```

instead ?

You could debug the requisition using Chrome Developer Tools, and see the response code. If the URL is wrong it should return 404. If nothing appears in Chrome DT or Firebug it means your Ajax request is not being fired and it's not a URL problem.

Comment: Yes I am. Because of the router of the app. See my comment to Spokey's suggestion.

Comment: Could you try to hit F12(developer tools) and see the response code? If the URL is wrong it should return 404.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your *URL* is wrong. You say the absolute path is

```
http://localhost:8080/serviceordersystem/index.php/warrantyqueries/add
```

but by using `/warrantyqueries/add` your *URL* will result in

```
http://localhost:8080/warrantyqueries/add
```

You must use the absolute path in order for this to work.

**P.S:** From experience I had problems with `$.ajax()` and `http://localhost`. You may want to consider using the IP instead if this still fails.

---

For future debugging you may consider opening your browser console and see for errors and network requests. Also consider expanding your error method.

For example

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}
```

Taken from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

> error Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String
>   errorThrown )

Comment: In a working form I have seen that the action of this form is <form id="ServiceorderAddForm" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="/serviceordersystem/index.php/serviceorders/add"> ... So I guess the url should be /serviceordersystem/index.php/warrantyquery/add ... Tried that. Still no success.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with debugging. Did an update of my "simple function". Still there is no output.

Comment: @mosquito87 does it alert error? if yes please see the response like in my answer